# How can I use variables from one thread class activity to other activity which don't contains thread class

Tags: java, android, sockets, java-threads

I am new to android development and threading. I have one activity which has Thread class which is receiving continues values through socket programming. I am not able to use these values in other activities.
My thread class activity code is as below

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static double target_range;
public static double target_height;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainn);
     theight= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.from_server_height);
    thread.start();
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void run () {

        while(true) {

            try {
                Socket s = new Socket("192.168.50.188", 8054);
                DataInputStream input=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());             
                    while(input.readLine()!=null){
                        String st=input.readLine();
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                           String[] splitStr = st.trim().split("\\s+");
                            target_range= Double.parseDouble(splitStr[0]);
                            target_height= Double.parseDouble(splitStr[1]);
                            trange.setText(String.valueOf(target_range));
                            theight.setText(String.valueOf(target_height));
                            
                      
                        }
                    });
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

});
```

now I am accessing it in other activity but when I assigned target_range and target_height variable my variable values always be 0.0
code for it is below

```
public static double target_range_1 = FirstActivity.target_range;
public static double target_height_1 = FirstActivity.target_height;
```

here target_range_1=0.0 and target_height_1=0.0
while if direct print using UI or

```
System.out.println(FirstActivity.target_range+","+FirstActivity.target_height);
//it will print accurate value like 220.234,450.90
```

I am not able to figure out why it is not get assigned to target_range_1 and target_height_1

Comment: yes its running...

Comment: i have given just required code ... I have declared all the variables and  all textviews

Comment: yes i started thread and its running correctly....I am just not able to override or assigned those variable in other activity...how can I do that...assume all  programme running correctly

Answer (score 0):

A few things to note here:

1- A class' static variables are initialized when it is first loaded. And since your shared variables are primitive, you are simply copying them to the `OtherActivity` class the first time the `OtherActivity` is loaded. Any changes made past this point are not reflected in the variables defined in the `OtherActivity`. Remove these two variables and access the `target_range` and `target_height` directly:

```
public static double target_range_1 = FirstActivity.target_range;
public static double target_height_1 = FirstActivity.target_height;
```

2- Declare the `FirstActivity.target_range` and `FirstActivity.target_height` variables as `volatile` or use `AtomicDouble` instead of the primitive `double`. In Java, sharing a variable between multiple threads without proper synchronization or atomic access is undefined behavior.